# Why must I set the tail first before connecting two partitions? Partition List - LeetCode

Tags: go, linked-list

Currently working on Partition List in LeetCode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-list/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150

My original solution is as follows:

When I set beforeCurr.Next to after.Next as to try to link my beforeList and my afterList, I get an error of memory limit exceeded for this case, head := [1], x := 2.

```
func partition(head *ListNode, x int) *ListNode {
    before := &ListNode{-1, head}
    after := &ListNode{-1, head}

    beforeCurr := before
    afterCurr := after
    curr := head

    for curr != nil {
        if curr.Val < x {
            beforeCurr.Next = curr
            beforeCurr = beforeCurr.Next
        } else {
            afterCurr.Next = curr
            afterCurr = afterCurr.Next
        }
        curr = curr.Next
    }
   
    // CODE IN QUESTION HERE
    beforeCurr.Next = after.Next
    afterCurr.Next = nil

    return before.Next
}
```

If I do this instead the code passes:

```
afterCurr.Next = nil 
beforeCurr.Next = after.Next
```

What is causing the error to occur? I am struggling to understand why the order in which I set the pointers matter for this case.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `afterCurr` and `after` are pointing to the same node for the example you gave. That's why the order of operations matter. Setting `afterCurr.Next` also sets `after.Next`